# CDDB API for a Java application

Tags: java, api, mp3, musicbrainz

I'm planning to make a Java application for tagging mp3 files. My first choice was Discogs but I have problems accessing the covers: in the JSON response they are too small, and i get `HTTP 403 - Forbidden` from those that appear on the web. So I've seen some alternatives like `freedb`, `MusicBrainz` and `AMG LASSO`. So I would like to know from other users who have worked with one of these tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MusicBrainz has a [Cover Art Archive](http://coverartarchive.org) (CAA) together with archive.org.

There is a [CAA Java API](https://github.com/lastfm/coverartarchive-api) available for the cover art archive and a [MusicBrainz Java API](http://code.google.com/p/musicbrainzws2-java/).
You can use the MusicBrainz API to find the MBID for the release and then the CAA API to find the matching cover art for the release MBID. Note that discogs master releases correspond to release groups in MusicBrainz.

Not all MusicBrainz releases do have cover art in this archive, yet. Some only have links to Amazon ASINs where clients then retrive the coverart from.
Some Python code explains what URLs have to be used: [Picard coverart module](https://github.com/musicbrainz/picard/blob/master/picard/coverart.py).

I am sure freedb doesn't host coverart or has anything like that linked. However, you can search other databases with freedb IDs (CDDB ID). For MusicBrainz there is a [FreeDB Gateway](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/FreeDB_Gateway).

Comment: What happened to Cover Art Archive? Seems emptied.